# Leverage browser caching - nginx with CDN

Tags: angular, performance, nginx, google-cloud-platform, cdn

I'm testing my site with `pingdom`:
https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/dCLQGc/https://stagingreport.daytwo.com

And getting a low grade in leverage browser caching:
[image]

All static files being served from an nginx server with the following configuration

```
server {
   listen 80;

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_types    text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css;


    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


}
```

Because I'm **using google cloud CDN** I didn't setup any caching configuration on server.

**In order to get a higher performance score
should I change something in the nginx configuration?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [caching details](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching) mentioned below, you might need to configure the nginx accordingly:

> A response can be stored in Cloud CDN caches only if all of the
>   following are true:
>
> It was served by a backend service or backend bucket with Cloud CDN
>   enabled.
>
> It is a response to a GET request.
>
> Its status code is 200, 203, 206, 300, 301, 302, 307, or 410.
>
> It has either a Content-Length header or a Transfer-Encoding header.
>
> It has a Cache-Control: public header.
>
> It has a Cache-Control: s-maxage, Cache-Control: max-age, or Expires
>   header.
>
> It has a Content-Length, Content-Range, or Transfer-Encoding header.
>
> Its size is less than or equal to the maximum size.
>
> For backend buckets, you can satisfy these requirements by marking the
>   object as shared publicly.
>
> There are also checks that block caching of responses. A response is
>   not cached if any of the following are true:
>
> It has a Set-Cookie header.
>
> It has a Vary header with a value other than Accept, Accept-Encoding,
>   or Origin.
>
> It has a Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, or private directive.
>
> The corresponding request had a Cache-Control: no-store directive.